# I am trying to get the right Api query to get a single response from the collection, but I keep getting list of all responses in my recyclerview

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin, retrofit

//URL -- https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards?q=name:gardevoir

```
    @GET("v2/cards")
    fun getSinglePokemon(@Query("name")query: String): Single<PokemonResponse>
```

Comment: I tried it but gives: retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 404

Comment: Try @GET("v2/cards") fun getSinglePokemon(@Query("q")name: String): Single<PokemonResponse>